# How to run an SQL file with sqlplus in Powershell ISE

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I want to execute an SQL file with sqlplus, but when I try to in Powershell ISE the result says how to use sqlplus. [The result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl4k7.png)

The code I used in the example in ISE is:

```
sqlplus "username/password@database @C:Path\To\file.sql"
```

But when I run this code in CMD or regular Powershell it works without problems. The result is just some dummy `Select 1 from dual`.

I have tried to put the path in a single qoute( ' ) with and without the @ (inside and outside of the quote) but nothing is working. I also didn't find much when googling the issue.

I also tried just to connect and it works without problems, although I can't type anything after it connects. [Result with just the connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/571GY.png)

Answer (score 0):

because you are doing wrong

the real syntex is

```
sqlplus username/password@TnsAlias 'c:\path\to\DBscript.sql' | out-file 'c:\temp\sql- output.txt'
```

I think you (') use early.

or try this without outfile

```
$output = sqlplus username/password@TnsAlias 'c:\path\to\DBscript.sql'
```

store in variable

Comment: I have tried both, [my code](https://i.imgur.com/1rimiLl.png) the first one being the original. But when I check the txt file I get the same result just some [genreal info](https://i.imgur.com/2hb6Onb.png) on sqlplus

Comment: Figured it out with the help of Idrish's anwser, I just had to remove the quotation marks in my original code and it worked. Took me way to long...